# How to tell Yum a program was manually removed

Tags: linux, centos, yum, centos7

If I install a piece of software using Yum, and then upgrade that software building from source, how do I tell Yum to not overwrite the source built software the next time Yum sees an 'upgrade' for the software?

Can I tell yum that it was manually uninstalled so that it thinks the yum installed version is no longer there?

I don't want to yum uninstall the software first and then build because I want to keep the service scripts and auxiliary things from the yum package

Answer (score 1):

Found a [manual](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rh_yum_cheatsheet_1214_jcs_print-1.pdf)(Careful its pdf) from Red-Hat regarding `yum`.
Your targets should be `yum check` or `yum history`.

With `yum history` you can view and edit your yum database.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to touch the package you have installed you simply add it on the `exclude list` on `/etc/yum.conf`

So, if for example the package you want to ignore is `httpd` then you add the following to `/etc/yum.conf` after the `[main]` section

```
[main]
exclude=httpd*
```

Depending on the package you may want to add an `*` after the package name to match any packages starting with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either installonlypkgs or exclude in yum.conf will do the job